# Will you be able to see kernel panic output in the terminal?

Tags: crash

If a Linux distro crashed with the GUI running, and the terminal app was open, will you be able to see kernel panic output in the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

The terminal app is not showing you what happens under the hood. The terminal app is a second instance allowing you to run terminal commands, but it is not the same as the core, and therefor a crash will not be shown to the terminal app.

If you however switch from the GUI to the console shell and a crash happens, it will be shown there as much as it is possible depending on the crash.

It is basically the same as running services can log to the console shell, but you don't see that logging in the terminal app either.